# long equation in two column paper (the mathtool doesnt work.)

Tags: equations

I have an equation which is too long for a two-column paper. the code that I write is like below :

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
J=\frac{\displaystyle -l_2}{\displaystyle sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)}\cdot
\begin{matrix}
sin(\theta_1)sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)+sin(\theta_2)sin(\theta_1-\theta_3)&-sin(\theta_2)sin(\theta_4-\theta_3)\\
-cos(\theta_1)sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)-cos(\theta_2)sin(\theta_1-\theta_3)&cos(\theta_2)sin(\theta_4-\theta_3)
\end{matrix}
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

but it doesn't work.what can i do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to introduce some new symbols such as `Z=\sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)` in order to get it easier to read and shorter to typeset.

Assuming that you need all those terms in *one* equation, you could possibly do like the following:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
    \begin{multline*}
        J=\frac{-l_2}{\sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)}\cdot \\
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \begin{split}&\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)\\&\quad+\sin(\theta_2)\sin(\theta_1-\theta_3)\end{split}&-\sin(\theta_2)\sin(\theta_4-\theta_3)\\[3ex]
            \begin{split}&-\cos(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)\\&\quad-\cos(\theta_2)\sin(\theta_1-\theta_3)\end{split}&\cos(\theta_2)\sin(\theta_4-\theta_3)
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{multline*}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For maximum readability, you may put the equation at the bottom of the page like this (without the need to modify the equation at all):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath,lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2} %
\enlargethispage{-2cm}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,-600){\hspace{-\parindent}\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\hrulefill
\vspace*{4pt}
\begin{equation*} \label{eqn_first}
J=\frac{\displaystyle -l_2}{\displaystyle sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)}\cdot\
\begin{bmatrix}
sin(\theta_1)sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)+sin(\theta_2)sin(\theta_1-\theta_3)&-sin(\theta_2)sin(\theta_4-\theta_3)\\
-cos(\theta_1)sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)-cos(\theta_2)sin(\theta_1-\theta_3)&cos(\theta_2)sin(\theta_4-\theta_3)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}}}
\end{picture}%
\enlargethispage{-2cm}
\lipsum[1-6]
\lipsum[2-5]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

We have to shrink the remaining text to leave room for the equation by `\enlargethispage{-2cm}`. You can control the space as needed. There is also a `widetext` [package](https://svn.einsteintoolkit.org/documents/Paper_EinsteinToolkit_2010/widetext.sty) that you could try.

Another good option is to use shortcuts by introducing new symbols:

```
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{equation*}
J=\frac{\displaystyle -l_2}{\displaystyle sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)}\cdot\
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where,

$A=sin(\theta_1)sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)+sin(\theta_2)sin(\theta_1-\theta_3)$

$B=sin(\theta_2)sin(\theta_4-\theta_3)$

$C=-cos(\theta_1)sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)-cos(\theta_2)sin(\theta_1-\theta_3)$

$D=cos(\theta_2)sin(\theta_4-\theta_3)$

\lipsum[2-5]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, but please use `\sin\cos`. If you put the last example in align, you can use `\shortintertext{where,}` from `mathtools` and get much better spacing.